# Interface class inside callback function causes crash

Tags: c++, user-interface, callback, fltk

The code is pretty straigh-forward. The code works if there isn't `IDumb` and I pass `dumbClass` directly to `dumbWin`. But when dumbClass has IDumb interface, the code crashes at `print()`.

```
using namespace std;

class IDumb {
public :
virtual void print() = 0;
};

class dumbClass : public IDumb {
public :
void print() {
    cout << "this is dumb class" << endl;
}
};

class dumbWin : public Fl_Window {
IDumb *dc;
public:
dumbWin(IDumb *dc) : Fl_Window(100, 100, "win") {
    Fl_Button *b = new Fl_Button(10, 10, 50, 25, "OK");
    b->callback((Fl_Callback*)callbk, this);
    end();

    this->dc = dc;
}

void print() {
    dc->print();
}

static void callbk(void *p) {
    cout << "OK" << endl;
    ((dumbWin*)p)->print();
}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
IDumb *dC = new dumbClass();
dumbWin *dW = new dumbWin(dC);
dW->show();

return Fl::run();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call call `b->callback` before setting `this->dc`. Would that be a problem? You're better off with member initialization:

```
dumbWin(IDumb *dc) : Fl_Window(100, 100, "win"), dc(dc)
```

Also, provide a virtual destructor for IDumb.

Comment: Didn't work. If I call `dc->print()` in constructor of `dumbWin` it works. Only when I call it in callback, it fails!

Comment: Could you provide more details on how it crashes? What is the call stack?

Comment: I just get `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. Is there any way to view the call stack? I'm using Eclipse

Comment: You need to run this thing under debugger. I never debugged C++ under eclipse. Try "Debug As" rather than "Run As".

Comment: yes. I tried single stepping
when the dc->print() is called in constructor the message prints fine
but when dc->print() is called from the callback, it gives cannot access memory

Comment: I can't chat from work, and SO does not like long comment chains. You need to carefully use the debugger to look at all the data. In particular, compare `this` in the constructor with the parameter passed to callback. Compare dc at the end of the constructor with dc at in the callback.

Comment: Solved it by changing static void `callbk(void*)` to `static void callbk(Fl_widget*, void*)`

Comment: The giveaway line (which I missed) was `b->callback((Fl_Callback*)callbk, this);`. The cast tells us that something is wrong with the callback function. No cast should be necessary.